# WCF Client Callback

Tags: wcf

I have a two Winform applications (each running on a different computer) which communicate over WCF and essentially follow the client/server model.  The client will send out a JSON packet on a channel and the WCF service handles the incoming request.  The WCF service has a custom event handlers which is triggered when the service receives this new incoming packet and the server application subscribes to these events so it can be notified.  When the event handler fires, it passes the parsed JSON packet over to the server application, which then runs through a long process that is launched in a separate thread (using a backgroundworker) so as to not lock up the server application UI.  So... I've got all of that stuff working.

However, now what I need to do is to figure out how to send a call back message to the client whenever the backgroundworker thread has completed its process to let them know that everything has been completed.  The server knows the IP address of the client who sent it the message because I added that attribute as part of the JSON packet which is originally sent over.  However, I have no idea how to get the server to send information back to client in this instance.  I've gone through the tutorials and I know that I can simply add a return variable on the function that the client uses to send the data over to the host application... but in this case I don't think that would work because I have to wait for a separate thread to complete before sending the return variable.  Can anyone provide a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for WCF [Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is bi-directional (clients can send and subscribe to the service).

There's a walk through on MSDN: [How To: Create a Duplex Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Brad do you think your post is subject to _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_  Maybe summarise it?  Thanks